# Cron job should run every 15 minutes , but it should NOT run between 9:00 (AM) to 10:00 (AM)

Tags: cron

How to run a Cron job every 15 minutes , but it should NOT run between 9:00 (AM) to 10:00 (AM).

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
 * 0,15,30,45 0-9,10-23 * * ?
```

The above CRON says to run on the hour, 15, 30, and 45 minutes past the hour, from midnight to 9am, and from 10am to midnight.  This excludes 9am-10am which was your requirement.